# Cron job with PHP script doesn't work properly

Tags: php, cron

One of my customers have PHP script which loads cvs file. When he execute this script via WWW it works properly - logs of loaded data are stored in /var/php/CLIENT/loaded.log. But when i try to execute the same script by the same user which Apache executes it and with the same config (php.ini) i recive no data in loaded.log. The same situation if i do this by Cron. Syslog says that Cron recive any errors.

Have you got any clues where i should search?

Comment: enable logging and you'll see your error, `php` and `php-cli` are different

Comment: script is executed as: su - USER -c "php5.3 /path/to/script/" it used THE SAME user as Apache uses to run this script with the same configuration. I don't know where else i should set logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PHP scripts work when run via Apache but not via cron, some common issues can be that the script uses variables only available during a web request such as `$_SERVER` variables (e.g. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or others) or `$_GET` variables, or it could be a different PHP is used for web requests vs. command line.

Try running the script yourself in shell using the su command you listed but after `php5.3`, add `-d display_errors=on` and see if you get any error output.